# Using multi-cores for increased parallel performance

Tags: multithreading, compiler-construction, multiprocessing

I see the point of having, say, a quad core computer, is being to increase throughout. But I'm wondering at exactly what stage of normal day-to-day computing this is happening.

If I write C code to do a matrix multiplication (the "Hello World" of parallel computing) will the compiler on my system automatically know how to optimize this for all 4 cores? Or would I have to explicitly create multiple threads in my program to take advantage of all 4 cores?

Basically what I want to know is how much of a program is made parallel automatically versus how much a programmer can optimize by making multiple threads that the scheduler will send to the different cores.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty much if you write a program in any the languages you know about, it won't run in parallel.

To get parallelism in such languages, you have to resort either to built-in language features ("fork" or "do parallel") or to external libraries that somehow use threading.

The functional language guys claim one of the principal values is that there are no side effects, so in fact your entire functional program can be executed in parallell.  I find it astonishing that the Haskell guys then proceed to provide you with (and as far as I can tell, insist you use) explicit parallelism primitives where you want it.

Comment: Alright, so let me ask this: what is the difference between writing a multithreaded program (via Forks and whatnot) versus using something like OpenCL?

Comment: So OpenCL lets you describe operations you want to give to a GPU like device.  The *giving it to the GPU* is sequential; the GPU acts like a funny hardware library that has parallel execution built into what it does.  So, you didn't actually get implicit parallelism; you had to organize it yourself.   Fortran95 has whole-array operations; some compilers will automatically compile those as (data parallel) operations.

Answer (score 2):

You have to create multiple threads yourself if you write in pure C, or use OpenMP (very appropriate for matrix multiplication; you can write code to split the work in a loop to multiple thread with OpenMP) to generate the threading code for you.

However, load balancing must be done by you.

A program must have multiple threads to be able to run on different cores.

Answer (score 1):

The system does **NOT** know how to spread the work between cores.  It's up to you to write your program to split the workload.  This is only worthwhile when you have a lot of work to be done.  That's one of the big things threads are for.

Answer (score 1):

An increasing number of frameworks and language-integrated features are making declarative parallel computing easier. However, it will still require you to make some changes to your code. The amount of change can be small (a few lines) or large (complete rewrite), depending on the nature of the code and whether there is a good fit between your code and the framework.

There are ways to parallelize that does not require you to manage threads. Those are often termed task-parallelism, data-parallelism, actor, agent, etc.